# Installing M2DOC

Tags: windows, java

I need install M2DOC for using Office Open XML language (OOXML). The guide at url :

http://obeonetwork.github.io/M2Doc/download/

### say that:

To install M2Doc on Obeo Designer:

= Download an Obeo Designer.
   = Then you need to unpack the bundle and launch the executable.
   = Install the M2Doc update site: all versions.

### That’s it! You are ready to start with M2Doc.

I've installed (Windows x64 version under windows 7) Obeo Designer and running ok, but when start the executable M2DOC.exe or launcher.exe (inside the package m2doc-win32.win32.x86_64.zip) the following message popup:

[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6AlY.png)

Please, help me. I'm not an expert.

Tks in advance
Feel
Italy

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download OD](https://www.obeodesigner.com/en/download) and unpack it. Then start the executable.
Then go to the help menu and select install new software.
Add the [M2Doc update site](http://obeonetwork.github.io/M2Doc/download/) for instance:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/obeo-m2doc-releases/2.0.3/repository

Then select the update site you just added, select all the proposed features and click the install button.